# connecting sql server 2008 from sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am not able to connecting to the sqlserver 2008 from my sqlserver 2005....Is it really not possible to connect or there is some way..

please suggest me..if there is some thing..
Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Is it from the server or are you using SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2005 Management Studio is not forward-compatible with SQL 2008.

You'll need to install the 2008 version of the tool (which will allow you to connect to 2008/2005/2000).